# How the .cpp file is linked to the header file?

Tags: c++, linker, header-files

I have one .h file, one .cpp file and one main.cpp file.

#### a.h

```
class abc {
      abc();
      ~abc();
      void dispaly();
};
```

#### implementation.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
void abc::dispaly()
{
 cout << "inside .cpp file";
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include<a.h>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
  abc obj;
  obj.dispaly();
}
```

Now this program executes properly without any errors(Ignore syntax errors if any). In the main program i only included "a.h" file and not included "implementation.cpp". i don't understand how the implementation.cpp file is linked to the header file and main.cpp file?

Comment: you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6264256/113608

Comment: What are you using to compile your code? The linking doesn't happen in source. The linking is the last thing to be done before building the executable or library.

Comment: My guess is that you're using an IDE and both source files are included in your project.

Comment: I'm executing in linux machine using g++